# Communicate between two Raspberry Pis using USB-Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, serial, communication

I have two raspberry pis I want to communicate between. For convenience, let's say one is always the talker and the other is always the listener. The listener's ethernet port is occupied by another connection. Is there a way I can send messages from the talker to the listener over an RJ45-RS232USB cable? The RJ45 connects to the talker and shows up at the listener side as /dev/ttyUSB0. Is there a way I can write a message (maybe UDP) to the port on the talker end and have it appear on the serial port at the listener end?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not connect everything to a router or even cheaper a network switch?  Then all the devices could talk to each other over Ethernet using any protocol you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this - this is a good idea, but I have restrictions on space and power that are causing me to rely on a single link between the two pis.

Comment: Do you exactly want a solution for the setup you described or do you want a solution to your general problem? There may be other/better possibilities.